# How to implement a table filter in Angular 13?

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to implement a table filter in my angular 13 project. I got a nice code from the below source:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-table-multi-select-pipe?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftable-filter.pipe.ts

But, I am getting below errors maybe because the code is old. Please suggest me how can I resolve these errors.

Errors:-

```
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'Object'.
  No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'Object'.ts(7053)
```

[image]

Comment: Will `Record<string, any>` work instead of `Object`? e.g. [typescriptlang](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgBWGApgGhW9AVKAQwDsBnAM2hDgF85yoJqByAARIHMBXAG0KgD0AY2jpmAbgCwAKBmtUGABQIZcOMUIh0ALjjMYhAEY90AMWA8Y6KMxk0AlDPQAPSLDhC+pUnDxGT5pbWCuhwoGAmWsQwPiEEJBRUiDKqcDBEZJRQIIo8wKQwuiQAngDaALrY5BZWUKS6AEroIlAAJgA8BVDAxBzYJQB89snSamoiZPAA1ujFPmNjALxwAPKGAFbNMAB0M3OK1UF19tuHtYp7cIsD9DXWpKV75fZSo2MTBbdHAKqk1ldwRRcP5QXRIUrOXRdHoccpFYjFcS0YbXOB7UjbdAAN2sxQusyuN2B1kes3KV0WyzO91JxWer1Saig6BgXCgxDRswxJl6MAAFnAAPxwPIFU53KAHCW-azDXSimCvNQ0FLSGhAA)

Comment: Perfect. It is working. It would be great if you please explain this solution or provide any references. You can answer it below so I can mark it as accepted.